# Request not showing all data in array

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel, laravel-5.1

```
I am using laravel 5.1 and I am in the middle of the problem.
```

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var counter = 0;

    $(document.body).on('click', ".popCategory", function () {

        var appendcategory = "";

        if (counter < 100) {
            counter++;
            appendcategory += '<input type="text" class="form-control"   name="category[]" placeholder="Category" value="545454" />';
            $('.category_append').append(appendcategory);
        }
    });
</script>
```

As shown in image I have appended the category with the help of jquery and   when I submit the form I get the result as shown in below:
[image]

The problem is that I only get one value when I have submitted three value of category . you can see the inspect element below:

[image]

```
<form action="" role="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="current_amount" placeholder="Amount" id="current_amount" min="1"/></td>
    <td><select name="cash_flow_status" class="form-control">
     <option value="cashin">CashIn</option>
        <option value="cashout">CashOut</option>
          </select></td>
         <td class="category_append">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="category[]" placeholder="Category" value="545454"/>

             </td>
      <td>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="popCategory">
          <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
       </td>
     <td class="item_append"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="items[]" placeholder="Items"/></td>
      <td>
     <div name="add1" class="btn btn-success cashFlowAddPart" onClick="appendItems()" ><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div></td>
      <td colspan="2">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="cashflowsubmit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success"/>
        </td>
       </form>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: keep jquery code..

Comment: i have included jquery code

Comment: Do you submit three or 1 with value and other no values?

Comment: i have appended three category input box and filled with value but when i submit the form i just get the first data in array

Comment: Is the inspector screenshot a current one? Can't see the category[counter] to work properly...

Comment: You don't need to do this : `name="category[' + counter + ']"` . Simply putting `name="category[]"` to all inputs of category will save them in an array, no need of a counter.

Comment: Depends, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682266/laravel-5-multiple-form-inputs-with-the-same-name-but-keeping-the-order

Comment: i know but i had just tried because of my friend suggestion but it is still not working

Comment: But if i put three category input text manually with out append code, the arrray shows the data all the data..but not while i am using append..

Comment: How do you submit the form? Normal submit button or jQuery?

Comment: normat submit button ..i have used laravel request

Comment: You should try to `console.log(counter);` because I don't think it is working as it should display count in the `counter[]`.

Comment: you don't need counter actually

Comment: var categoryarray= new Array(); 
    $('input[name="category"]').each(function(){categoryarray.push($(this).val());}); try this in jquery...

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: @LalKumarRai, when you submit the form, all the elements having property ```name``` gets posted to the route you have defined in form action. Your problem is ```name=category[]```, this will not be treated as an array on server but a simple field with name ```category[]```. If you want to submit an array, create that many fields in your form or post an object using Ajax.

Comment: why don't it is being treated as an array?

Comment: @LalKumarRai for test add few category input box without using javascript and post it, check whether it submit or not